# My program crashed when using shared_ptr, what's wrong with this code?

Tags: c++, qt, shared-ptr

I'm learning smart pointers but i don't understand it very well, What I have already known is that it will auto delete the object it points to, but i have no idea why my program crashes. Please see the following code:

```
#include <QVector>
#include <memory>
using std::shared_ptr;
using std::make_shared;

class Node;
typedef shared_ptr<Node> NodePtr;

class Node {
  public:
    Node(){};

    NodePtr AddInput(NodePtr n){
        // i wanted to convert the "Node* this" to shared_ptr<Node>, 
        // thus it can be added to n->outputs_.
        NodePtr this_ptr(this);  


        if (!inputs_.contains(n)) {
            inputs_.append(n);
        }
        if (!n->outputs_.contains(this_ptr)) {
            n->outputs_.append(this_ptr);
        }
        return this_ptr;
    }

  public:
    QVector<NodePtr> inputs_;
    QVector<NodePtr> outputs_;
};


int main(){
    auto g1 = make_shared<Node>();
    auto g2 = make_shared<Node>();
    g2->AddInput(g1);
    g1->outputs_.clear();  // the program crashes when executing this line
    return 0; // never goes here
}
```

the program crashes when executing `"g1->outputs_.clear()"` but it's OK when I replace it with `"g2->inputs_.clear()"` ? Why ? What happened ? How should I fix it ?

Comment: Can you briefly summarize your understanding of what `NodePtr this_ptr(this);` means, why the shown code needs it, what this does, and how you believe this works. This is not what shared pointers are all about.

Comment: You declared a pointer but never initialized it. Try assigning a node to the node pointer before working with it.

Comment: Looks like what you  seek is [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) and its support.

Comment: i wanted to convert a Node* to shared_ptr<Node>, thus it can be added to the vector of outputs_.

Comment: An arbitrary pointer cannot be converted from a plain pointer to a shared_ptr. `shared_ptr` is only for instances of classes that were constructed in dynamic scope. That's the sole reason for their existence. There is no guarantee, whatsoever, that an arbitrary pointer will point to an object that was created in dynamic scope, and in all cases the object must derive from `std::enabled_shared_from_this`, and even if it did, it still must be created in dynamic scope. See [a good C++ textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: A `Node` also containing vectors of `Node`s is also a bad smell.

Comment: The main problem with your attempt is you now have TWO completely distinct `shared_ptr`s that manage the object , `g2` in `main` and `this_ptr` in `Node::AddInput`.   You only want one `shared_ptr` and copies of that one `shared_ptr`. Every `shared_ptr` contains a reference to lifetime tracking information for the managed object. When you copy a `shared_ptr`, the copy refers to the same tracking information as the original. If you make a new `shared_ptr` you get a whole new set of tracking information.

Comment: thanks! i learned a lot, my problem is solved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks, [`shared_from_this()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) solves my problem

```
class Node : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Node>
{
  public:
    Node(){};
    NodePtr AddInput(NodePtr n){
        NodePtr this_ptr = shared_from_this();

        if (!inputs_.contains(n)) {
            inputs_.append(n);
        }
        if (!n->outputs_.contains(this_ptr)) {
            n->outputs_.append(this_ptr);
        }
        return this_ptr;
    }

  public:
    QVector<NodePtr> inputs_;
    QVector<NodePtr> outputs_;
};
```

Comment: Recommendation: Spend a few lines explaining what went wrong in the question and how this code resolves the problem. This makes the answer more useful in the future because the next person to encounter this problem won't have identical code, but if they have a good explanation they'll be able to spot and understand the differences between the original and the answer more easily and learn how to avoid the problem in the future.